# How to use buffer() in QGIS Value Relation field

Tags: qgis, buffer

When adding a point, I'd like to auto-populate one of its fields (the street address) setting it to a field in the nearest point in another layer (a layer containing all existing addresses).

It looks like the Value Relation edit widget could do the trick, if I could figure out how to use the `buffer()` function.

Right now, I can get the list of all addresses by selecting the `Layer`, `Key` column and `Value` column. I thought I could filter that list so that it has only nearby points (ideally just one), using something like:

`within($geometry_A, buffer($geometry_B,50)) = 1`

where `$geometry_A` is the new point and `$geometry_B` is the existing point.

`$x`, `$y` and `$geometry` seem to refer to the existing points in the selected `Layer`.

Assuming I am on the right track, how do I refer to the geometry of the new point (i.e. `$geometry_A`)?

[image: screenshot]